# Can we set author to the db user in liquibase for update?

Tags: liquibase, author

In liquibase, "author" is normally hardcoded in the changeset. But we want to set it to the db user against which the changeset is being run. So we will have the author `dev_schema` in dev, and `prod_schema` in prod and so on. The db user are not known beforehand, so we like to set at runtime automatically from --username option of liquibase connection string.

```
./liquibase.bat --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --changeLogFile="changelog.xml" --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" --username=dev_schema ...
```

In the changeset tag I set the attribute author to `${username}` but it is not picked up.

```
<changeSet author="${username}" ...
```

Also tried setting the environment variable, which worked, but then you have to set the same username twice. There is also a risk that if someone uses a different username, liquibase will fail to execute due to checksum failure.

Is that possible? Alternatively, any way around?

Comment: You could create your own [extension](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/pages/2424849/ChangeLogParser) and override the `Change` and then modify it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that username is liquibase's system parameter and it is not used in changelog for placeholder replacement. Try to specify parameter like java param `-Dusername=<your user>` and let's see what will happen.

Comment: As I mentioned setting the environment variable works but you have to set it twice: one as '--username' and then as '-Dusername'. Also there is a risk of failing liquibase update if -Dusername is set wrongly. I am looking for a way to use the same username which is used to connect to the database.

Comment: did you tried with liquibase.properties file? I don't know which properties parser is used there but maybe there could be potential feature where you can set something like `liquibase.author=${user}` and then you can use `${author}` as author. But I never tried this.